# iPhone: UITableview background image stretch/pull/scroll up beyond the view bounds

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, background-image

I have a very specific requirement to fulfil.

[image]  [image]

Lets say this is my original background image (on the right).

[image]

This is how my image should be on the screen by default.

[image]

And this is how it should be when I do a "pull down" gesture on the `UITableView`.

I want to set an image (shown above) as a view's background.  A `UITableView` to be specific.

NOTE: Image size is more than the view size.

When I try to pull down the view beyond the bounds of the view, the image should continue to show up and should not break. With the current implementation the image from the bottom part shows up.

Any ideas how I can achieve this? Pardon me if the solution is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by only one line of code

```
[yourView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourBGImgName.png"]]];
```

**OR Alternately**

put one `UIScrollView` and set it's background color with above way and you can find your background repeating when you scrolling your scrollView.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work. I think I might not have clearly specified my requirement. Hence I have updated the question once again. Thanks for taking out time.

Answer (score 0):

Set the top part as the background for a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` in the header and do the same for the footer. Then set a negative inset for your tableView.

Something like

```
[self.tableView setContentInset:(UIEdgeInsets){-headerHeight, 0, -footerHeight, 0}];
```